# How to animate spinner so it expands with its options

Tags: android, animation, spinner

Curently i have a spinner which, as expected, when clicked pops out with list where i can choose item. I need to animate it so that when clicked, its view expands downwards and other options are shown there without any poping out.
My searching concluded that it is hard/not possible to animate spinner so i tried making listview with margin and lowering that margin in custom Animation, but that squished that list.

My current spinner code:

`MainActivity`

```java
adapter = new ProfileChoiceSpinnerAdapter(this, items, profiles);
loginBinding.profileNameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

```java
public class ProfileChoiceSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context ctx;
    private List<String> contentArray;
    private List<ExtendedProfile> profilesWithAuthNumber;

    public ProfileChoiceSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> contentArray, List<ExtendedProfile> profilesWithAuthNumber) {
        super(context, R.layout.profile_choice_spinner_values_layout, R.id.spinner_profile_name, contentArray);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.contentArray = contentArray;
        this.profilesWithAuthNumber = profilesWithAuthNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ImageView spinnerDropdownIcon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_dropdown_icon);
        if(position != 0)
            spinnerDropdownIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return convertView;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_choice_spinner_values_layout, null);
        }

       // populating single element ...

        return convertView;
    }
```

`main_activity`

```xml
...
                        <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/profile_name_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_290sdp"
                        android:layout_height="67dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_shape_white"
                        android:popupBackground="@drawable/button_shape_white"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
...
```

Any ideas or sollutions? If my descriptions are not clear enough let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up nesting instead of spinner a Listview, setting it as non scrollable and with animation changing its height when clicked. When some element other then the one at top of list is clicked i move it to first position and collapse height to one element height